# How is this simple add numbers and output code doesn't work? (Whitespace language)

Tags: esoteric-languages, whitespace-language

I want the code to output 5,  which is got from 2+3 (inputted from stack manually)

```
[space][space][space][tab][space] push 2
[space][space][space][tab][tab] push 3
[tab][space][space][space] add together
[tab][lf]
[space][tab] output number
```

But it seems to say that it is a invalid line end? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Push commands should end with a line feed,
so it should probably be (in a one-instruction-per-line format, i.e., only the annotated characters are significant)

```
[space][space][space][tab][space][lf]
[space][space][space][tab][tab][lf]
[tab][space][space][space]
[tab][lf][space][tab]
```